# Changing style of not routed component depending on route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a navbar with `routeLinks`.
Now I want to change the size of the navbar depending on which route I'm at.

Is there a way to do this (change class of navbar or inject css rule)? I would like to keep the `routeLinks`, so no js code for the routing.

Comment: I've solved it using a router subscription and changing a variable and a binded class. But maybe there's a better / more beautiful solution.

Comment: You want to change the size of the whole navBar or the size of the selected option from the navbar?

Comment: Of the whole navBar.

Comment: Not sure if its the best way, but the way I would do it is add a list of options in the NavBar @Component, and add a click handler on each option that calls a `selectOption(this)` method and send himself to be set as the current option, and based on which one is selected you change the class of the style of your navbar depends on how many options you have. Something similar to this: `[class.option-1-class]="selectedOption==options[0]"`